# How does MSAL for java play with Edge browser accounts with multiple devices?

Tags: java, state, single-sign-on, mismatch, msal

We modified the servlet authentication example into a tomcat SSO valve using MSALJ 1.13.10. Works fine for all chrome browsers. However, our enterprise rolled out Edge browser "account sync" across devices,but then stopped due to license issues. So now, I have a user who has 4 computers each with edge browsers, and 2 of his 4 computers/devices show up in his Edge Account -> settings -> Manage Account -> Device list, which are the Edge clients that DO NOT work with SSO (we get session/state mismatch errors from MSAL). The other edge browser clients are not in the device lilst, and DO work with MSAL SSO.

So I guess my question becomes how does MSALJ play with MS Edge browser account syncing with multiple devices?

We tried to have each edge browser peform SSO for a servlet based web app, but it seems if the edge browser account has multiple devices then SSO won't work due to MSAL reporting state mismatch errors.